# Методы классификации в машинном обучении

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn, классификация

Существует некая задача классификации: на обучение классификатор получает массив строк в качестве класса и некоторые числа в качестве параметров.

Есть ли такие методы, не используя нейросетей, которые позволяют классифицировать подобные выборки? В каком направлении двигаться?

Пример:

**Обучение:**

RW, LW, CAM -> 75,45,22,78,98,76

CB -> 56,54,66,77,25,56

CB,RB,RCB -> 45,56,78,97,44,22

CAM,CM,CDM -> 34,45,65,77,88,93

**Предсказание**:

34,56,76,88,99,23 -> CAM,CM,RW

24,56,90,98,77,66 -> ST,LW,RW

34,45,87,98,77,55 -> RB,CB

Не могу решить задачу, тк пока не знаю про методы с несколькими классами для объекта.

Буду благодарен советам!

Comment: Метод ближайшего соседа попробуйте (KNN).

Comment: Опишите подробнее датасет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это совершенно классическая, можно сказать - базовая задача теории классификации. Изложена в любой даже не книге, а в любом блоге по машинному обучению. Находиться в один клик:
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Задача_классификации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)
https://tproger.ru/translations/scikit-learn-in-python/
https://evergreens.com.ua/ru/articles/classical-machine-learning.html
https://wiki.loginom.ru/articles/classification-problem.html
http://www.aiportal.ru/articles/autoclassification/methods-class.html

и.т.д. А вот какой именно метод использовать - решается на основе, как соответствующих теоретических ограничений, так и сравнения результатов их применения.

Comment: Ну тут не просто классификация, тут надо несколько лейблов повесить на данные. Не помню как это называется. Это как на картинку нейросеть "смотрит" и говорит - там есть КОТ, ДЕРЕВО, ТРАВА.
Хотя можно конечно свалить в кучу все данные по каждому лейблу и потом каждый лейбл опять же отдельно предсказывать есть он или нет.

Comment: Это называется "множественная классификация", "многоклассовая классификация" , "classification with multiple classes", в некоторых предметных областях 'многовариантная диагностика' -  суть не меняется. О ней даже написано в первой данной мною ссылке. Что-бы понять, как оно работает - надо начать с двухклассовой классификации. В некоторых случаях многоклассовой классификации ее вообще сводят к последовательности  ряда одноклассовых. Но не всегда. Например -  деревья решений очень легко работает с несколькими классами напрямую.